# Ef and Dapper.net in one solution

Tags: entity-framework, dapper

Is there a reason why I couldn't use both EF and Dapper.NET in my solution?? EF like to use due to the flexibility of the programming , but when I need to select several large amounts of data then used the Dapper. Can it lead to any conflict???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't cross the streams, you should be fine. In fact, I **strongly suggest** using more than one tool; use EF when you want to use features that are key to EF, and dapper when you need simpler data access and care more about performance than complexity / flexibility. Forcing a single tool to do things it doesn't excel "because we use Tool X" is usually where projects go wrong.